# how to insert selected candidate in helm buffer into previously selected buffer?

Tags: helm

I'm often in the situation, that I am looking for variables and functions with helm. However when I find whatever I was looking for and I want to use it in my code I close the helm buffer, start typing and try to complete the name with company.

It's really annoying to type again after I already found the candidate I was looking for. So the question is, how can I insert the currently selected helm candidate into the previous buffer ?

Comment: What are you using to look up variables and functions? `helm-apropos`? If so, there is currently no way to insert the candidate into the buffer. If you'd like to implement such functionality, take a look at `C-c i` in `helm-find-files-map`, which eventually calls `helm-insert-file-name-completion-at-point` in `helm-files.el`.

Comment: I usually use `describe-variable` and `describe-function`. Thanks for the hint regarding `helm-find-files-map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `C-c C-k` to add the current candidate to the kill ring.  Pressing `C-y` will then insert it into the current buffer as usual.

If you want to paste the candidate directly into the buffer, you can use `helm-copy-to-buffer` with `C-c C-i`.